# How do I insert text into the SSH PANEL

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How do I insert text, with what combinations?
SSH-in-browser Google?

[image]

Comment: please add details and context to your question. and if you mean by inserting text while changing password in SSH, by default there are no characters that will be shown while typing the password, unless you didn't type any password. as for the combination, make sure to apply the standard/best practice to create a secure password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating your password over SSH, no characters are displayed by default while typing the password, unless you don't have one, in which case it will prompt an error. Follow the standard/best practice for creating a secure password when it comes to the combination.